# cd drive is not list under bootable divice

Tags: boot, bios, bootable-media, optical-drive

how do i make my CD drive a bootable  device

Comment: Wow, I've never heard of the PythonC#RoR language!  Cool hybrid, I wonder how that works...

Comment: What does this have to do with python? Or c#? Or, indeed, RoR for that matter!

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to go to the BIOS settings. The moment your machine starts, see what combination you need to press - it should tell you. It is usually <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>, but it can be anything.

Then, look for something that says boot settings, or boot order, and change it so that optical drive is first.

I cannot give more precise information because it is different on different BIOSs.

If this is a once off thing for a new OS, I recommend that instead you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or whatever the shortcut key is on your machine that says "Show Boot Menu". This should allow you to set the CD as bootable once without making any system wide changes.